# How can I refresh data on click in Leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

```js
var alabamalang = ['SpeakonlyEnglishathome', 'Spanish', 'French', 'Patois', 'Cajun', 'FrenchCreole', 'Italian', 'Portuguese', 'German', 'Yiddish', 'PennsylvaniaDutch', 'Dutch', 'Afrikaans', 'Swedish', 'Danish', 'Norwegian', 'Icelandic', 'Greek', 'Russian', 'Polish', 'Serbocroatian', 'Croatian', 'Serbian', 'Ukrainian', 'Czech', 'Bulgarian', 'Macedonian', 'Slovene', 'Armenian', 'Persian', 'Hindi', 'Gujarati', 'Urdu', 'Indian', 'Bengali', 'Panjabi', 'Marathi', 'Kashmiri', 'Nepali', 'Sindhi', 'Pakistann', 'Sinhalese', 'Romany', 'JamaicanCreole', 'Pidgin', 'Romanian', 'Welsh', 'IrishGaelic', 'Albanian', 'Lithuanian', 'Latvian', 'Pashto', 'Chinese', 'Cantonese', 'Mandarin', 'Formosan', 'Japanese', 'Korean', 'Mon-Khmer,Cambodian', 'Hmong', 'Thai', 'Laotian', 'Vietnamese', 'Turkish', 'Dravidian', 'Telugu', 'Kannada', 'Malayalam', 'Tamil', 'Burmese', 'Mien', 'Tagalog', 'Indonesian', 'Malay', 'Bisayan', 'Pangasinan', 'Micronesian', 'Chamorro', 'Marshallese', 'Palau', 'Ponapean', 'Trukese', 'Samoan', 'Hawaiian', 'Navajo', 'Aleut', 'Eskimo', 'Algonquian', 'ChastaCosta', 'Apache', 'Kiowa', 'Sahaptian', 'Dakota', 'Choctaw', 'Mikasuki', 'Koasati', 'Muskogee', 'Cherokee', 'Zuni', 'AmericanIndian', 'Hungarian', 'Arabic', 'Hebrew', 'Amharic', 'Cushite', 'Sudanic', 'Swahili', 'Bantu', 'Mande', 'Fulani', 'Kru,Ibo,Yoruba', 'Efik', 'Finnish', 'Estonian', 'Caucasian', 'Mayanlanguages', 'Oto-Manguen','"Uncodable"'];
var arizonalang = ['SpeakonlyEnglishathome', 'Spanish', 'French', 'Patois', 'FrenchCreole', 'Italian', 'Portuguese', 'German', 'Luxembourgian', 'Yiddish', 'PennsylvaniaDutch', 'Dutch', 'Afrikaans', 'Swedish', 'Danish', 'Norwegian', 'Icelandic', 'Greek', 'Russian', 'Polish', 'Serbocroatian', 'Croatian', 'Serbian', 'Bielorussian', 'Ukrainian', 'Czech', 'Slovak', 'Bulgarian', 'Macedonian', 'Slovene', 'Armenian', 'Persian', 'Hindi', 'Gujarati', 'Urdu', 'Indian', 'Bengali', 'Panjabi', 'Marathi', 'Bihari', 'Rajasthani', 'Oriya', 'Assamese', 'Nepali', 'Sindhi', 'Pakistann', 'Sinhalese', 'Romany', 'JamaicanCreole', 'Krio', 'Romanian', 'IrishGaelic', 'ScotticGaelic', 'Albanian', 'Lithuanian', 'Latvian', 'Pashto', 'Kurdish', 'Ossete', 'Chinese', 'Hakka', 'Cantonese', 'Mandarin', 'Formosan', 'Wu', 'Japanese', 'Korean', 'Mon-Khmer,Cambodian', 'Hmong', 'Thai', 'Laotian', 'Vietnamese', 'Kazakh', 'Kirghiz', 'Uighur', 'Turkish', 'Mongolian', 'Tungus', 'Dravidian', 'Telugu', 'Kannada', 'Malayalam', 'Tamil', 'Munda', 'Tibetan', 'Burmese', 'Karen', 'Mien', 'Tagalog', 'Indonesian', 'Malay', 'Sundanese', 'Bisayan', 'Sebuano', 'Ilocano', 'Bikol', 'Pampangan', 'Carolinian', 'Chamorro', 'Marshallese', 'Palau', 'Trukese', 'Yapese', 'Melanesian', 'Polynesian', 'Samoan', 'Tongan', 'Fijian', 'Hawaiian', 'Navajo', 'Aleut', 'Eskimo', 'Inupik', 'Yupik', 'Cheyenne', 'Cree', 'Ojibwa', 'Ottawa', 'Athapascan', 'Ahtena', 'Hupa', 'Apache', 'Kiowa', 'Siuslaw', 'Sahaptian', 'Pomo', 'Cocomaricopa', 'Mohave', 'Yuma', 'DeltaRiverYuman', 'Havasupai', 'Walapai', 'Yavapai', 'Hidatsa', 'Mandan', 'Dakota', 'Omaha', 'Choctaw', 'Keres', 'Mohawk', 'Cherokee', 'Paiute', 'SouthernPaiute', 'Shoshoni', 'Hopi', 'Pima', 'Yaqui', 'Tewa', 'Towa', 'Zuni', 'AmericanIndian', 'SanCarlos', 'Hungarian', 'Arabic', 'Hebrew', 'Amharic', 'Berber', 'Chadic', 'Cushite', 'Sudanic', 'Nilotic', 'Nilo-Saharan', 'Swahili', 'Bantu', 'Mande', 'Fulani', 'Kru,Ibo,Yoruba', 'Efik', 'Mbum(andrelated)', 'African', 'Finnish', 'Estonian', 'Caucasian', 'Basque', 'Syriac', 'Aztecan', 'Mayanlanguages', 'Oto-Manguen', 'Quechua', 'Chibchan', '"Uncodable"'];
var puertoricolang = ['SpeakonlyEnglishathome', 'Spanish', 'French', 'FrenchCreole', 'Italian', 'Portuguese', 'German', 'Dutch', 'Greek', 'Russian', 'Polish', 'Ukrainian', 'Bulgarian', 'Persian', 'Hindi', 'Urdu', 'Bengali', 'Nepali', 'Catalonian', 'Romanian', 'Chinese', 'Cantonese', 'Mandarin', 'Japanese', 'Korean', 'Vietnamese', 'Telugu', 'Tagalog', 'Ilocano', 'Chamorro', 'AmericanIndian', 'Arabic', 'Hebrew', 'Finnish', '"Uncodable"'];

var alabama = alabamalang[Math.floor(alabamalang.length * Math.random())];
var arizona = arizonalang[Math.floor(arizonalang.length * Math.random())];
var puertorico = puertoricolang[Math.floor(puertoricolang.length * Math.random())];

var statesData = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
    {"type":"Feature","id":"01","properties":{"name":"Alabama","RhetoricalDiversity":5.2, "Englishonly":94.8, "Spanish":3.2, "IndoEuro": 0.8,"AsPac": 0.9, "Other": 0.3, "language": alabama},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-87.359296,35.00118],[-85.606675,34.984749],[-85.431413,34.124869],[-85.184951,32.859696],[-85.069935,32.580372],[-84.960397,32.421541],[-85.004212,32.322956],[-84.889196,32.262709],[-85.058981,32.13674],[-85.053504,32.01077],[-85.141136,31.840985],[-85.042551,31.539753],[-85.113751,31.27686],[-85.004212,31.003013],[-85.497137,30.997536],[-87.600282,30.997536],[-87.633143,30.86609],[-87.408589,30.674397],[-87.446927,30.510088],[-87.37025,30.427934],[-87.518128,30.280057],[-87.655051,30.247195],[-87.90699,30.411504],[-87.934375,30.657966],[-88.011052,30.685351],[-88.10416,30.499135],[-88.137022,30.318396],[-88.394438,30.367688],[-88.471115,31.895754],[-88.241084,33.796253],[-88.098683,34.891641],[-88.202745,34.995703],[-87.359296,35.00118]]]}},
    {"type":"Feature","id":"04","properties":{"name":"Arizona","RhetoricalDiversity":27.2, "Englishonly":72.8, "Spanish":20.6, "IndoEuro": 2.0,"AsPac": 2.1, "Other": 2.6, "language": arizona},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-109.042503,37.000263],[-109.04798,31.331629],[-111.074448,31.331629],[-112.246513,31.704061],[-114.815198,32.492741],[-114.72209,32.717295],[-114.524921,32.755634],[-114.470151,32.843265],[-114.524921,33.029481],[-114.661844,33.034958],[-114.727567,33.40739],[-114.524921,33.54979],[-114.497536,33.697668],[-114.535874,33.933176],[-114.415382,34.108438],[-114.256551,34.174162],[-114.136058,34.305608],[-114.333228,34.448009],[-114.470151,34.710902],[-114.634459,34.87521],[-114.634459,35.00118],[-114.574213,35.138103],[-114.596121,35.324319],[-114.678275,35.516012],[-114.738521,36.102045],[-114.371566,36.140383],[-114.251074,36.01989],[-114.152489,36.025367],[-114.048427,36.195153],[-114.048427,37.000263],[-110.499369,37.00574],[-109.042503,37.000263]]]}},
    {"type":"Feature","id":"72","properties":{"name":"Puerto Rico","RhetoricalDiversity":94.6, "Englishonly":5.4, "Spanish":94.5, "IndoEuro": 0.1,"AsPac": 0.0, "Other": 0.0, "language": puertorico},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-66.448338,17.984326],[-66.771478,18.006234],[-66.924832,17.929556],[-66.985078,17.973372],[-67.209633,17.956941],[-67.154863,18.19245],[-67.269879,18.362235],[-67.094617,18.515589],[-66.957694,18.488204],[-66.409999,18.488204],[-65.840398,18.433435],[-65.632274,18.367712],[-65.626797,18.203403],[-65.730859,18.186973],[-65.834921,18.017187],[-66.234737,17.929556],[-66.448338,17.984326]]]}}
    ]};

 var map2 = L.map('map2').setView([37.8, -96], 3);

 L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
  maxZoom: 5,
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
   '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
   'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
  id: 'mapbox/light-v9',
  tileSize: 512,
  zoomOffset: -1
 }).addTo(map2);


 // control that shows state info on hover
 var info = L.control();

 info.onAdd = function (map2) {
  this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
  this.update();
  return this._div;
 };

 info.update = function (props) {
  this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>Language Presence</h4>' +  (props ?
   '<b>' + props.name + '</b><br />' + props.language
   : 'Hover over a state');
 };

 info.addTo(map2);

 function style(feature) {
  return {
   weight: 1,
   opacity: 1,
   color: 'white',
   dashArray: '3',
   fillOpacity: 0.7,
   fillColor: '#1f78b4'
  };
 }

 function highlightFeature(e) {
  var layer = e.target;

  layer.setStyle({
   weight: 5,
   color: '#666',
   dashArray: '',
   fillOpacity: 0.7
  });

  if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
   layer.bringToFront();
  }

  info.update(layer.feature.properties);
 }

 var geojson;

 function resetHighlight(e) {
  geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
  info.update();
 }

 function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  layer.on({
   mouseover: highlightFeature,
   mouseout: resetHighlight,
   click: highlightFeature
  });
 }

 geojson = L.geoJson(statesData, {
  style: style,
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature
 }).addTo(map2);

 map2.attributionControl.addAttribution(' | Language Data &copy; <a href="http://census.gov/">US Census Bureau</a> (American Community Survey TableID: 1601)' );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew==" crossorigin=""></script>
    <style>#map2 { top-margin: 50px; height: 500px; }
    .info { padding: 6px 8px; font: 14px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background: white; background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8); box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); border-radius: 5px; } .info h4 { margin: 0 0 5px; color: #777; }
    .legend { text-align: left; line-height: 18px; color: #555; } .legend i { width: 18px; height: 18px; float: left; margin-right: 8px; opacity: 0.7; }</style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="map2"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="shifting.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I have a Leaflet map with data for each US state in a variable called "statesData." The stateData has a math.random function in it, so every time I reload the page, different data appear for each corresponding state. As it stands, everything works fine. However, I'd like to perform this same function by clicking on states rather than having to refresh the page.

I think the easiest way for me to get this done is to add a function on click. I added a "refreshData" function, but I'm not sure where to go from here. I tried "remove()", but that removed the entire state boundaries and data. This time I tried "resetStyle()", which clears the current data, but it doesn't add new one.

Edit: I've attached a snippet, but with only a few states because of length allotment in snippet. The original map accounts for all states.

```
var geojson;
    function resetHighlight(e) {
        geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
        info.update();

}

function refreshData(e) {
    geojson.resetStyle(statesData);
    info.update();
}

    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
            mouseover: highlightFeature,
            mouseout: resetHighlight,
            click: refreshData
        });
    }

    geojson = L.geoJson(statesData, {
        style: style,
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    }).addTo(map2);
```

Comment: Can you give an example with a snippet, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the exact answer to the OP but here is my two-cents. 
In my opinion it is better to keep the geographical data separate from the non geographical data.  So first I created some function `stateNGData` (non geographical data). This function return  an object with a method `shufffle` for easy shuffling of the state language. I then created the object data.
In this way it is easy to retrieve|update what ever information about the state in question.

```
 function stateNGData(state, lang) {
  return {
  stateName: state,
  language: lang,
  shuffle: function() {
    return lang[Math.floor(lang.length * Math.random())];
  }
}
```

}

```
var data = {};
data['Alabama'] = stateNGData("Alabama", alabamalang);
data['Puerto Rico'] = stateNGData("Puerto Rico", puertoricolang);
data["Arizona"] = stateNGData("Arizona", arizonalang);
```

Once this is done, we just need to add a function that will update the feature of a state  and associate it with a click event.

```
function updateFeature(e) {  
  var prop = e.target.feature.properties ; 
  prop.language = data[prop.name].shuffle();
  info.update(layer.feature.properties);
 }
```

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
      layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature,
        mouseout: resetHighlight,
        click: updateFeature
      });
    }

This will update only the state on which the cursor is. So if you want to update all, it is better to update the data and render the map again. Another solution could be to update only the style and leave the data as they are.

```js
var alabamalang = ['SpeakonlyEnglishathome', 'Spanish', 'French', 'Patois', 'Cajun', 'FrenchCreole', 'Italian', 'Portuguese', 'German', 'Yiddish', 'PennsylvaniaDutch', 'Dutch', 'Afrikaans', 'Swedish', 'Danish', 'Norwegian', 'Icelandic', 'Greek', 'Russian', 'Polish', 'Serbocroatian', 'Croatian', 'Serbian', 'Ukrainian', 'Czech', 'Bulgarian', 'Macedonian', 'Slovene', 'Armenian', 'Persian', 'Hindi', 'Gujarati', 'Urdu', 'Indian', 'Bengali', 'Panjabi', 'Marathi', 'Kashmiri', 'Nepali', 'Sindhi', 'Pakistann', 'Sinhalese', 'Romany', 'JamaicanCreole', 'Pidgin', 'Romanian', 'Welsh', 'IrishGaelic', 'Albanian', 'Lithuanian', 'Latvian', 'Pashto', 'Chinese', 'Cantonese', 'Mandarin', 'Formosan', 'Japanese', 'Korean', 'Mon-Khmer,Cambodian', 'Hmong', 'Thai', 'Laotian', 'Vietnamese', 'Turkish', 'Dravidian', 'Telugu', 'Kannada', 'Malayalam', 'Tamil', 'Burmese', 'Mien', 'Tagalog', 'Indonesian', 'Malay', 'Bisayan', 'Pangasinan', 'Micronesian', 'Chamorro', 'Marshallese', 'Palau', 'Ponapean', 'Trukese', 'Samoan', 'Hawaiian', 'Navajo', 'Aleut', 'Eskimo', 'Algonquian', 'ChastaCosta', 'Apache', 'Kiowa', 'Sahaptian', 'Dakota', 'Choctaw', 'Mikasuki', 'Koasati', 'Muskogee', 'Cherokee', 'Zuni', 'AmericanIndian', 'Hungarian', 'Arabic', 'Hebrew', 'Amharic', 'Cushite', 'Sudanic', 'Swahili', 'Bantu', 'Mande', 'Fulani', 'Kru,Ibo,Yoruba', 'Efik', 'Finnish', 'Estonian', 'Caucasian', 'Mayanlanguages', 'Oto-Manguen', '"Uncodable"'];
var arizonalang = ['SpeakonlyEnglishathome', 'Spanish', 'French', 'Patois', 'FrenchCreole', 'Italian', 'Portuguese', 'German', 'Luxembourgian', 'Yiddish', 'PennsylvaniaDutch', 'Dutch', 'Afrikaans', 'Swedish', 'Danish', 'Norwegian', 'Icelandic', 'Greek', 'Russian', 'Polish', 'Serbocroatian', 'Croatian', 'Serbian', 'Bielorussian', 'Ukrainian', 'Czech', 'Slovak', 'Bulgarian', 'Macedonian', 'Slovene', 'Armenian', 'Persian', 'Hindi', 'Gujarati', 'Urdu', 'Indian', 'Bengali', 'Panjabi', 'Marathi', 'Bihari', 'Rajasthani', 'Oriya', 'Assamese', 'Nepali', 'Sindhi', 'Pakistann', 'Sinhalese', 'Romany', 'JamaicanCreole', 'Krio', 'Romanian', 'IrishGaelic', 'ScotticGaelic', 'Albanian', 'Lithuanian', 'Latvian', 'Pashto', 'Kurdish', 'Ossete', 'Chinese', 'Hakka', 'Cantonese', 'Mandarin', 'Formosan', 'Wu', 'Japanese', 'Korean', 'Mon-Khmer,Cambodian', 'Hmong', 'Thai', 'Laotian', 'Vietnamese', 'Kazakh', 'Kirghiz', 'Uighur', 'Turkish', 'Mongolian', 'Tungus', 'Dravidian', 'Telugu', 'Kannada', 'Malayalam', 'Tamil', 'Munda', 'Tibetan', 'Burmese', 'Karen', 'Mien', 'Tagalog', 'Indonesian', 'Malay', 'Sundanese', 'Bisayan', 'Sebuano', 'Ilocano', 'Bikol', 'Pampangan', 'Carolinian', 'Chamorro', 'Marshallese', 'Palau', 'Trukese', 'Yapese', 'Melanesian', 'Polynesian', 'Samoan', 'Tongan', 'Fijian', 'Hawaiian', 'Navajo', 'Aleut', 'Eskimo', 'Inupik', 'Yupik', 'Cheyenne', 'Cree', 'Ojibwa', 'Ottawa', 'Athapascan', 'Ahtena', 'Hupa', 'Apache', 'Kiowa', 'Siuslaw', 'Sahaptian', 'Pomo', 'Cocomaricopa', 'Mohave', 'Yuma', 'DeltaRiverYuman', 'Havasupai', 'Walapai', 'Yavapai', 'Hidatsa', 'Mandan', 'Dakota', 'Omaha', 'Choctaw', 'Keres', 'Mohawk', 'Cherokee', 'Paiute', 'SouthernPaiute', 'Shoshoni', 'Hopi', 'Pima', 'Yaqui', 'Tewa', 'Towa', 'Zuni', 'AmericanIndian', 'SanCarlos', 'Hungarian', 'Arabic', 'Hebrew', 'Amharic', 'Berber', 'Chadic', 'Cushite', 'Sudanic', 'Nilotic', 'Nilo-Saharan', 'Swahili', 'Bantu', 'Mande', 'Fulani', 'Kru,Ibo,Yoruba', 'Efik', 'Mbum(andrelated)', 'African', 'Finnish', 'Estonian', 'Caucasian', 'Basque', 'Syriac', 'Aztecan', 'Mayanlanguages', 'Oto-Manguen', 'Quechua', 'Chibchan', '"Uncodable"'];
var puertoricolang = ['SpeakonlyEnglishathome', 'Spanish', 'French', 'FrenchCreole', 'Italian', 'Portuguese', 'German', 'Dutch', 'Greek', 'Russian', 'Polish', 'Ukrainian', 'Bulgarian', 'Persian', 'Hindi', 'Urdu', 'Bengali', 'Nepali', 'Catalonian', 'Romanian', 'Chinese', 'Cantonese', 'Mandarin', 'Japanese', 'Korean', 'Vietnamese', 'Telugu', 'Tagalog', 'Ilocano', 'Chamorro', 'AmericanIndian', 'Arabic', 'Hebrew', 'Finnish', '"Uncodable"'];


function stateNGData(state, lang) {
  return {
    stateName: state,
    language: lang,
    shuffle: function() {
      return lang[Math.floor(lang.length * Math.random())];
    }
  }
}
var data = {};
data['Alabama'] = stateNGData("Alabama", alabamalang);
data['Puerto Rico'] = stateNGData("Puerto Rico", puertoricolang);
data["Arizona"] = stateNGData("Arizona", arizonalang);

var statesData = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "01",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Alabama",
        "RhetoricalDiversity": 5.2,
        "Englishonly": 94.8,
        "Spanish": 3.2,
        "IndoEuro": 0.8,
        "AsPac": 0.9,
        "Other": 0.3,
        "language": data['Alabama'].shuffle()
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [-87.359296, 35.00118],
            [-85.606675, 34.984749],
            [-85.431413, 34.124869],
            [-85.184951, 32.859696],
            [-85.069935, 32.580372],
            [-84.960397, 32.421541],
            [-85.004212, 32.322956],
            [-84.889196, 32.262709],
            [-85.058981, 32.13674],
            [-85.053504, 32.01077],
            [-85.141136, 31.840985],
            [-85.042551, 31.539753],
            [-85.113751, 31.27686],
            [-85.004212, 31.003013],
            [-85.497137, 30.997536],
            [-87.600282, 30.997536],
            [-87.633143, 30.86609],
            [-87.408589, 30.674397],
            [-87.446927, 30.510088],
            [-87.37025, 30.427934],
            [-87.518128, 30.280057],
            [-87.655051, 30.247195],
            [-87.90699, 30.411504],
            [-87.934375, 30.657966],
            [-88.011052, 30.685351],
            [-88.10416, 30.499135],
            [-88.137022, 30.318396],
            [-88.394438, 30.367688],
            [-88.471115, 31.895754],
            [-88.241084, 33.796253],
            [-88.098683, 34.891641],
            [-88.202745, 34.995703],
            [-87.359296, 35.00118]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "04",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Arizona",
        "RhetoricalDiversity": 27.2,
        "Englishonly": 72.8,
        "Spanish": 20.6,
        "IndoEuro": 2.0,
        "AsPac": 2.1,
        "Other": 2.6,
        "language": data["Arizona"].shuffle()
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [-109.042503, 37.000263],
            [-109.04798, 31.331629],
            [-111.074448, 31.331629],
            [-112.246513, 31.704061],
            [-114.815198, 32.492741],
            [-114.72209, 32.717295],
            [-114.524921, 32.755634],
            [-114.470151, 32.843265],
            [-114.524921, 33.029481],
            [-114.661844, 33.034958],
            [-114.727567, 33.40739],
            [-114.524921, 33.54979],
            [-114.497536, 33.697668],
            [-114.535874, 33.933176],
            [-114.415382, 34.108438],
            [-114.256551, 34.174162],
            [-114.136058, 34.305608],
            [-114.333228, 34.448009],
            [-114.470151, 34.710902],
            [-114.634459, 34.87521],
            [-114.634459, 35.00118],
            [-114.574213, 35.138103],
            [-114.596121, 35.324319],
            [-114.678275, 35.516012],
            [-114.738521, 36.102045],
            [-114.371566, 36.140383],
            [-114.251074, 36.01989],
            [-114.152489, 36.025367],
            [-114.048427, 36.195153],
            [-114.048427, 37.000263],
            [-110.499369, 37.00574],
            [-109.042503, 37.000263]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "72",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Puerto Rico",
        "RhetoricalDiversity": 94.6,
        "Englishonly": 5.4,
        "Spanish": 94.5,
        "IndoEuro": 0.1,
        "AsPac": 0.0,
        "Other": 0.0,
        "language": data["Puerto Rico"].shuffle()
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [-66.448338, 17.984326],
            [-66.771478, 18.006234],
            [-66.924832, 17.929556],
            [-66.985078, 17.973372],
            [-67.209633, 17.956941],
            [-67.154863, 18.19245],
            [-67.269879, 18.362235],
            [-67.094617, 18.515589],
            [-66.957694, 18.488204],
            [-66.409999, 18.488204],
            [-65.840398, 18.433435],
            [-65.632274, 18.367712],
            [-65.626797, 18.203403],
            [-65.730859, 18.186973],
            [-65.834921, 18.017187],
            [-66.234737, 17.929556],
            [-66.448338, 17.984326]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};


var map2 = L.map('map2').setView([37.8, -96], 3);

L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
  maxZoom: 5,
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
    '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
    'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
  id: 'mapbox/light-v9',
  tileSize: 512,
  zoomOffset: -1
}).addTo(map2);


// control that shows state info on hover
var info = L.control();

info.onAdd = function(map2) {
  this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
  this.update();
  return this._div;
};

info.update = function(props) {
  this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>Language Presence</h4>' + (props ?
    '<b>' + props.name + '</b><br />' + props.language :
    'Hover over a state');
};

info.addTo(map2);

function str(p){
for (var key of Object.keys(p)) {
    console.log(key + " -> " + p[key])
}
}

function style(feature) {
  return {
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    color: 'white',
    dashArray: '3',
    fillOpacity: 0.7,
    fillColor: '#1f78b4'
  };
}

function highlightFeature(e) {
  var layer = e.target;

  layer.setStyle({
    weight: 5,
    color: '#666',
    dashArray: '',
    fillOpacity: 0.7
  });

  if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
    layer.bringToFront();
  }

  info.update(layer.feature.properties);
}

var geojson;

function resetHighlight(e) {
  geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
  info.update();
}

function updateFeature(e) {  
  var prop = e.target.feature.properties ; 
  prop.language = data[prop.name].shuffle()
  info.update(prop);
}


function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  layer.on({
    mouseover: highlightFeature,
    mouseout: resetHighlight,
    click: updateFeature
  });
}

geojson = L.geoJson(statesData, {
  style: style,
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map2);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin="" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew==" crossorigin=""></script>
  <style>
    #map2 {
      top-margin: 50px;
      height: 500px;
    }
    
    .info {
      padding: 6px 8px;
      font: 14px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      background: white;
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
      box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    .info h4 {
      margin: 0 0 5px;
      color: #777;
    }
    
    .legend {
      text-align: left;
      line-height: 18px;
      color: #555;
    }
    
    .legend i {
      width: 18px;
      height: 18px;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 8px;
      opacity: 0.7;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map2"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="shifting.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. This resolves my issue, and it does so more efficiently. I added the other state data, and it worked.